# How to retrieve my own comments from a public group on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to retrieve my own comments from a public group on Facebook, using the Facebook Graph API. This is a public group of which I am not an administrator.

I have attempted a number of strategies, but to no avail so far. I keep hitting brick walls, e.g.:

```
The xxx'yyy' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'user_managed_groups' permission.
```

If I go on my own profile activity log, I can see those comments, so I would have expected there should have been a way to retrieve those programmatically through the Graph API.

Am I mistaken?

**UPDATE**

On the chance that I am indeed mistaken, I have sent the following feedback to Facebook:

> I would like to b able to retrieve my own comments from a public group on Facebook, using the Facebook Graph API. This is a
>   public group of which I am not an administrator. 
>       At the moment, the Graph API documentation (v2.12) states that to read the feed I need to provide a user access token for an Admin of
>   the Group with the user_managed_groups permissions.
>       Please note that if I go on my own profile activity log, I can see those comments, so I would have expected there should have been a way
>   to retrieve those programmatically through the Graph API.

Comment: Group feeds are only accessible with an access token of a group admin now. _“so I would have expected”_ - wrong expectation; available via UI does not necessarily mean available via API.

Comment: @CBroe the question is "Am I mistaken?", so please, feel free to add your comment as a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group feeds are only accessible with an access token of a group admin now.

> Please note that if I go on my own profile activity log, I can see those comments, so I would have expected there should have been a way to retrieve those programmatically through the Graph API.

The main difference is, that you are one single person looking at your own data. But if I create an app and have a hundred thousand people log in to it and it was possible to read that data, then I could accumulate it for whatever shady purpose ...

(Now with the feed of a *public* group that might seem a little over the top, I know - but I think the general idea is to make automated data collection harder.)